# using opera unite to build a game server for realtime games

Tags: networking, opera

I want to ask for help in building an Opera Unite application as the game server for a 1 on 1 RTS game. (or other type of game which is **real time**)

descriptions:
The game is executed on client side by javascript, and connects to an Unite server for network play.

Users can play the game, without installing Unite, on a standard browser. The Unite server stays connected with the 2 players and synchronizes their game states in 1 on 1 gaming.

It is not intended to be a big server supporting thousands of players. It is to allow people to set up an instant, tiny game party with minimal configuration which Opera Unite fits very well. In this case the server and client are in the same local area network which the data transfer rate should be fast enough for gaming. Hope it also works in a wider network.

The Unite application should:

allows users to login into a room and set up a connection with the server. When two users logged into a room the game can then be started. The connection sends and receives data between server and client at a high rate of 12fps. The data is a string for maybe 200 characters long.

Can you outline the program flow of such a server? i.e. What should be done when receiving request. How to set up a P2P connection. How to ensure the connection is in "synchronization mode", that older data arrives earlier than newer data.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the other games in [Opera Unite section](https://unite.opera.com/applications/category/fun/) You can open them by unzipping and finding out how they have been built.